# power analysis for correlations

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-power

Does anyone know of a good method to run a power analysis for correlations whilst taking into consideration the number of trials of the task? I have used the package pwr in R to look at power but it does not take the number of trials into consideration.

Comment: If by number of trials, you mean number of measurements, more measurements increase reliabilty - which increases correlations (you can predict how much with the Spearman-Brown formula). You just power on the size of the correlation.  (Apologies if I have misunderstood.)

Comment: @Jeremy Miles By number of trials I mean the number of times participants will have to do the task. I know that the power increases with the number of trials but I am not sure how to actually account for it. Both Gpower and the pwr package do not incorporate the number of trials in the calculations.

Comment: Task? Trials? We need more details.

Comment: @Jeremy Miles Ok sorry, basically in my experiment participants have to do a experiment task (Psychology) that requires them to respond to the stimuli 1000 times. I want to see if having 1000 responses will increase the power of the study (I am sure it will). So I want to check what would be the required sample (participants) to find a correlation of .20 with 1000 responses per participant.

Comment: You need to know (or estimate) the reliability of the measure. You can then estimate how much larger the correlation will be when the reliability is higher. Then you calculate the power for that larger correlation.

Comment: You increase power more by increasing the number of people, compared with increasing the number of tasks. (200 people * 100 tasks > 20 people * 1000 tasks).

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but my task has to have 1000 responses per participant as it is a response time task. The correlation I want to look at actually would reflect the reliability of the task as I intend to correlate the results from one session with the results from another.

Comment: The reliability of the task (via the number of ratings) makes the correlation larger, so it increases power. You power based on that correlation.